# Why Saxon does not produce any file output?

Tags: xml, xslt, saxparser, saxon

XSLT parsers should produce an empty file even if there is no explicit text output. However, I have a situation where [Saxon-HE 9.3](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/#F9.3HE) does not produce any file output at all.

I compiled the files using this command:

```
Transform -s:1.xml -xsl:2.xsl -o:3.html
```

Whereby the contents of **1.xml** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- greeting.xml -->
<x>
<greeting>1</greeting><greeting>2</greeting>
</x>
```

And the contents of **2.xsl** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- greeting3.xsl -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:template match="/"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, there is no output (not even an empty file). **Neither is there any error message.**

What could have been the problem?

Comment: Good installation Pacerier ;-)!

Comment: Post a minimal example of the XML and the XSLT and we might be able to help. It is likely that your template matches and/or XPaths are not matching the XML structure, but there could be any number of reasons (case sensitivity, type-o, namespace mis-match, etc).

Comment: `1.xml` and `2.xsl` -- what do they contain? It is not just serious to say: "My program X when given the input Y produces no output" and not to show either X or Y -- regardles of the programming language your program is written in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely to be a bug or an "insufficient privileges" problem.

When the files **1.xml**, **2.xsl**, and **Transform.exe** are located in the desktop, there are no problems with the output.

But when the files are in `C:\`, it gives an error message:

> Failed to create output file file:/c://3.html: Access to the path 'c:\3.html' is denied.

Yet for some reason, when the files are in `C:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonHE9.3N\bin`, there's **no** output **and** **no** error message.

Comment: Do you know whether the Saxon executable was actually invoked? If it wasn't, there's not much I can do to improve the diagnostics ;-(. If it was invoked but failed to create an output file or error file for some basic reason, then perhaps there's an exception I'm not catching: it would be nice to have more details so it can be fixed.

Comment: @Michael i'm pretty sure its invoked take a look at this ss: http://imgur.com/yA3CW.gif

Comment: What happens if you add the -t option?

Comment: If there's no output from the -t option then it looks as if Saxon is trying to produce output and the system won't let it (either it's throwing an exception and Saxon is responding by producing more output which is equally invisible, or the system is discarding Saxon's output silently). Very strange. I don't really know what I can do about that. If anyone knows .NET well enough to tell me what I should be doing here, I'm happy to listen! Can you redirect the standard error output to a file, perhaps?

Comment: Depends on the shell but in many cases it's 2>error.log, I believe.

Comment: @Michael do you mean in the command prompt i type **Transform -s:1.xml -xsl:2.xsl -o:3.html 2>error.log**? if so i get `Access Denied`. running command prompt as admin, there are no errors (in other words i have the 3.html, and error.log file is empty)

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly possible for a transformation to be 100% correct and yet produce no output. Here's an example stylesheet that does just that:

```
<xsl:template match="/"/>
```

So the conjecture is that there's a bug in your code, and if you want us to help you find it, you'll need to show us your code.

Comment: even if i had `<xsl:template match="/"/>` there will be some *output*: an empty file. But i had no output whatsoever.. zilch. btw i've updated the question..